# how to get single id in many to many relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a student_class table that is mapping student with classes. I want to get student_id from this table with class ids as input. e.g:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2l0u.jpg]

Now I want a mysql query in which I will pass class_ids 3,5 and 9 and it should return me student_id 1.???

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without more specifics regarding your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another mysql specific approach

```
select student_id
from student_class
where class_id in (3, 5, 9)
group by student_id
having sum(class_id = 3) > 0
and sum(class_id = 5) > 0
and sum(class_id = 9) > 0
```

Comment: JazakAllah (Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `having`:

```
 select   student_id
 from     student_class
 where    class_id in (3, 5, 9)
 group by student_id
 having   count(distinct class_id) = 3
```

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword can do no harm, but would (hopefully) be redundant.

Comment: Indeed it would hopefully be redundant, but if a student decides to enrol for the same class twice (and the system does not forbid it), this query would still work.